# Keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, exception, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to make an array that outputs a pattern depending on how many rows and columns I give it for the input and I receive an error when it gets to the third method. I understand that the array begins at index zero and if i input (0 0) for the matrix it's out of bounds but i have no idea how to fix the problem. Thank you for the help!

Here is my code for the first class:

```
public class Transpose {

    public static int [][] createPatterned2DArray(int rows, int cols) 
        {
            int [][] table = new int [rows] [cols];                     
            for (int numRows = 0; numRows < table.length; numRows++){   
                for (int numCols = 0; numCols < table[0].length; numCols++){

                    table [numRows][numCols] = 10 + rows*(numRows +1) + numCols; 

                }
            }
            return table; 
        }


        public static void print2DArray (int[][] matrix) 
        { 
            for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++)
                {
                    System.out.printf("%-4d",matrix[row][col]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
        public static void print2DArrayTransposed(int [][] matrix)
        {   
            for (int row = 0; row < matrix[0].length; row++)
            { 
                for (int col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++)
                {
                    //try { 
                    //  if (matrix[0] == 0) {
                        //  System.out.println(matrix[0][0]); 
                    //  throw new Exception();
                        System.out.printf("%-4d",matrix [col][row]);
                    //  }
                    //catch (Exception e){
                    //  System.out.print(e);
                    }
                    System.out.println();

            }
        }
}
```

Here is the second class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestTranspose extends Transpose {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int rows = scan.nextInt(); 
    int cols = scan.nextInt(); 

    int [][] table = createPatterned2DArray(rows,cols);  
    print2DArray(table);
    System.out.println();
    print2DArrayTransposed(table);
    System.out.println();
  } 
}
```

This is the error that I am getting and its driving me insane! 
I can't seem to wrap my head around how to throw an exception or to make the output display nothing when i enter an input of (0 0) for the arrays. How can I correct this line of code that does not let me output an array of (0 0)?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Transpose.print2DArrayTransposed(Transpose.java:32)
at TestTranspose.main(TestTranspose.java:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't safely do `matrix[0].length` without first ensuring that `matrix.length != 0`.  In your other two methods, the outer loops on `row` take care of this.

But in `print2DArrayTransposed` it's your outer loop that's trying to do `row < matrix[0].length`; there's nothing to stop it trying to do that even when `matrix.length == 0`.  You can address this in one of two ways: add this early bail-out at the top of `print2DArrayTransposed`:

```
if (matrix.length == 0)
    return;
```

or change your outer loop on 'row' to:

```
for (row = 0; matrix.length > 0 && row < matrix[0].length; ++row)
```

Comment: thank you so much! i had something along the lines of that but i could nto figure it out for the life of me :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line of code in the `Transpose.print2DArrayTransposed()` method:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix[0].length; row++)
```

You are trying to access the first element of `matrix`, but there is no element because the length is zero.

A 0x0 array is valid, so no need to disallow creating the array in the first place. My suggestion would just be to simply check at the start of the method if the length of `matrix` is zero, and if so, just return because there is nothing to print (or print some helpful message instead).

```
public static void print2DArrayTransposed(final int[][] matrix) {
    if (matrix.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    //...
}
```